# Clock divider in vhdl from 100MHz to 1Hz code

Tags: vhdl, fpga, clock

I wrote this code for dividing the clock an a nexys4 fpga that has its integrated clock at 100Mhz frequency by default , and i need to divide it to 1hz. Can someone tell me if its correct or if not what needs to be changed ?

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity digi_clk is
port (clk1 : in std_logic;
       clk : out std_logic
     );
end digi_clk;

architecture Behavioral of digi_clk is

signal count : integer :=0;
signal b : std_logic :='0';
begin

 --clk generation.For 100 MHz clock this generates 1 Hz clock.
process(clk1) 
begin
if(rising_edge(clk1)) then
count <=count+1;
if(count = 50000000) then
b <= not b;
count <=0;

end if;
end if;
clk<=b;
end process;
end;
```

Comment: Generally, using logic to create a divided clock is not recommended in an FPGA. It should generate clock enables instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks OK.  However the existing code will produce an output frequency that is just below 1 Hz.  To get a precise 100000000:1 ratio, you will want to change the conditional statement from:

```vhdl
    if(count = 50000000) then
```

... to:

```vhdl
    if(count = 50000000-1) then
```

Comment: Technically true, but error is well below the tolerance of the oscillator on the OP's board, I bet.  Lucky if his board has a 50ppm clock.

Answer (score 0):

The program seems correct, but you should be declaring the internal signal (count) as an integer. Then your code should compile successfully. But you will get some warnings and will find some problems in testbech simulation. To avoid that you need to declare the internal signal ( count ) as: signal count : std_logic_vector (25 downto 0);  because 100MHz coded in 26 bits. I prefer to convert the 50000000 to Hexadecimal format and it should work without any problem.